# libusb can't open CDC device on Windows but it can on Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, libusb

I'm trying to communicate with a CDC device using libusb. The code I test is listed below;

```
    /* Initialize libusb
 */
rc = libusb_init(NULL);
if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
}

/* Set debugging output to max level.
 */
libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

/* Look for a specific device and open it.
 */
devh = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
if (!devh) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
}
```

Not: I take the code from https://github.com/tytouf/libusb-cdc-example/blob/master/cdc_example.c

I built the project for both windows and linux. In linux, program worked as expected. Device is successfully opened. But in windows, libusb cant open the device. Always return error "UNKNOWN_ERROR" (error code is 0xFFFFFFFb)

What could be error?

Comment: did you install [some sort of driver](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend#DriverInstallation) on windows?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I install the driver but problem still exist. Beside, I can access CDC device from any terminal program. Windows successfully enumarete the device.

Comment: what windows version are you on, which compiler are you using and what is the exact output of your program? and can you try executing it as administrator?

Comment: I use Visual Studio's compiler. I downloaded libusb-1.0 source code and compiled it using CMake (My Visual Studio version is 2017 community edition) Windows verison is Win7 and I execute as a administrator and nothing changes

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem today(only windows).

It turns out that libusb only works with the winUSB-Drivers.
You have to install them explicitly to your Device. Easiest for me was to use the [zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) installer(see link in the link in the comments above) to remove usbser driver and exchange it by the winusb one(for this one device).
Now the Device doesn't get enumerated as COM-Device, but registered as libusb32-Device/libusbKDevice or just USB-Device.

But i can open it in my host application.